# Fire an event from Timeline Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, timeline

I have been unable to successfully create an event with a click on a Google Timelien Chart. The Error I get is chart not defined. I ahve tried multiple answers on google.

Please let me know if you can figure out the error. If you understand how to use the getselection method or how to print the results of the table. It will also be helpful. The google timeline page does not have examples of selection from a timeline. it only has selections from table, bar or pie charts

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['timeline']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
        var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
        var primaryDataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        primaryDataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string' , id: 'LaborID' });
        primaryDataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string' , id: 'WOID' });
        primaryDataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string' , role: 'tooltip', p : {html:true}});
        primaryDataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date' , id: 'Start' });
        primaryDataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date' , id: 'End' });
        primaryDataTable.addRows([
          [ 'labor1', 'WO-1001' , '<b>Test</b>', new Date(2019, 3, 4), new Date(2019, 3, 5) ],
          [ 'labor1', 'WO-1002' , '<b>Test123</b>', new Date(2019, 3, 5),  new Date(2019, 3, 7) ],
          [ 'labor2', 'WO-2001' , '<i>Test123</i>', new Date(2019, 3, 4),  new Date(2019, 3, 5) ]

          ]);

         var primaryOptions = {
            title : 'Labor Assignment',
            tooltip: {isHtml: true },
            legend: 'none'
         }


        chart.draw(primaryDataTable, primaryOptions);
        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', myClickHandler);
      }

    function myClickHandler(){
  var selection = chart.getSelection();
  var message = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
    var item = selection[i];
    if (item.row != null && item.column != null) {
      message += '{row:' + item.row + ',column:' + item.column + '}';
    } else if (item.row != null) {
      message += '{row:' + item.row + '}';
    } else if (item.column != null) {
      message += '{column:' + item.column + '}';
    }
  }
  if (message == '') {
    message = 'nothing';
  }
  alert('You selected ' + message);
}


    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <td><div id="timeline" style="height: 380px; width: 900px"></div></td>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53767061/5090771), the event needs to be assigned, before the chart is drawn...